# read txt from ftp server getting error on codeigniter on fclose

Tags: php, ftp, codeigniter-3

I getting an error on Codeigniter on `fclose` when i using this code its seems a permission issue, then I tried to test it on separated php file to check that error and on normal php didn't return any error as screenshot.

This code is return the first plate matching with updated line.
and have no idea how to solve it.

```
$first_encountered_match = [];
$filename = "ftp://user:pass@path/file.txt";
$fi = fopen($filename, "r");
if (($handle = $fi) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        if (mb_strpos($data[9], "GGL-2125") === 0) {
            $first_encountered_match = $data;
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose($fi);

}
print_r($first_encountered_match);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2z4uG.jpg)

thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I used the codeigniter ftp library and works fine, thanks

```
$this->load->library('ftp');

$config['hostname'] = 'ftp.example.com';
$config['username'] = 'your-username';
$config['password'] = 'your-password';
$config['debug']        = TRUE;

$this->ftp->connect($config);
$this->ftp->close();
```